# WCF logging producing multiple svc file

Tags: c#, wcf, logging

I have a simple WCF service library called HelloService which is hosted in WCF Service application.

My service is hosted in remote IIS server. Below is my service configuration for logging.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error,ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Error">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="myUserTraceSource" switchValue="Error,ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="D:\HelloService\HelloServiceLogs.svclog"
    type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="xml"
    traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
</sharedListeners></system.diagnostics>
```

When I call this service, sometimes it logs in existing file and sometimes it creates new file.
[image: logFileCreated]

My questions are.

1) Why does it produces so many log files? How to write all logs in one file called.

2) How can I only log all unhandled exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can configure the size of messages using a configuration like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging 
         logEntireMessage="true" 
         logMalformedMessages="false"
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
         maxMessagesToLog="3000"
         maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

2) You can setup the level of logging, like this (error only in the example below):

```
<source propagateActivity="false" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: 1) After digging I found that I have set Maximum Worker Process property to 20 which was causing multiple file creation.

Comment: 2) I have one function in Service which just throws exception without catch block, after setting switchValue="Error" its not logging this exception. Any idea why?

Comment: You can set all levels you want to log, Error it's just one of them, you can use Warning, Critical,  multiple values separated by comma .... see more about all levels here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420538/Simple-Steps-to-Enable-Tracing-in-WCF

Comment: I tried all levels but no option is logging only unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Set for Critial only. Here is the documentantion, that says "Critical - Unhandled exceptions": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This worked. I was also looking at wrong window. All unhandled exceptions were logged in Message tab of Service Trace Viewer.